# Jenkins-Docker: Connection reset while connecting over VPN

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am running Jenkins via Docker on a RHEL server with this command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d --name jenkins-master -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

My problem is that if I RDP to a machine on the network, I am able to access the site at port 8080 of the host machine. If I try to access the site from my machine through VPN I get:

*This site can’t be reached The connection was reset.*

The difficult part for me is that running Django/Angular apps in Docker on the same server work fine; I am able to access those sites with no issue. iptables shows it is listening:

```
tcp        0      0 <ip>:8080      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

curl gives me the same error:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I've tried every combination of network/port mapping, but I don't understand why this particular application is resetting the connection, but my Django/Angular apps, which are configured identically, are working both through VPN and RDP to network machine.

Comment: VPN's can be susceptible to network MTU issues which will only hit large transfers.

Comment: Yeah I'm not transferring any files, just trying to hit the home page of Jenkins; and with the other sites working, I figure it has to do with Winstone, but I just don't know.

Comment: MTU is about 1400-1500 bytes. "large" being anything bigger than that will need to be split into multiple packets. Not that large really :) Often simple html will work but assets fail.